# How to query Active NameNode from Oozie

Tags: hadoop, oozie

In my hadoop cluster we have a namenode and a secondaryNameNode.

I am executing a step in my oozie job which must have the "active" name node.

Is there something which allows me to query the "active" name node from Oozie?

note that this is a fairly large cluster and there is no guarantee that Oozie and HDFS are co-located.

Edit:: Note that my question is not regarding Oozie configuration. The configuration is already done. My question is to query the active name node inside of the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you have active-passive/HA configuration - oozie should be configured using namespace not active namenode.

Comment: In other words, look into your `core-site.xml` config for property `fs.defaultFS` and use that alias for Oozie "nameNode".

Comment: BTW if you also have YARN with High Availability, don't worry about "jobTracker", it will be ignored (mandatory but ignored) as long as Oozie service has the appropriate config files in its CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudera support was able to answer this question for me.

The answer is documented here

http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-Processing-and-Workflow/Query-the-Active-Name-Node-from-an-Oozie-Job/m-p/34973#M1839